# talking to device in linux. WRITE function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

I'm trying to write a simple device driver, and use the **Dev_Read()** and **Dev_Write()** functions, which I have already defined.
My driver registers a character device tied to a
given major number this way

```
# mknod /dev/mydev c 250 0
```

And then, from my user program I open the device this way

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open("/dev/mydev", O_RDWR)) < 0)
{
  perror("open /dev/mydev");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

after I invoke the **Read()** function

```
int read_bytes = read (fd, buffer, 1);
```

and successfully get kernel space information, that my **Dev_Read** function works. 
My problem is that I don't understand how to implement my **Dev_Write** function.
How can I write someting to my file, to see that **Dev_Write** function works ? 
THANK YOU for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what you've tried which didn't work.

One thing to be aware of, and not necessarily intuitive, is that your driver's write function must copy the write buffer from the caller's space into kernel space. An example of that can be seen in the tutorial at http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux -

```
ssize_t memory_write( struct file *filp, char *buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {

  char *tmp;

  tmp=buf+count-1;
  copy_from_user(memory_buffer,tmp,1);
  return 1;
}
```

where `memory_buffer` is space you've allocated within your driver.

Comment: that is the devices write() function body. I have written it. Now I want to do something from userspace, to invoke that write() function from kernelspace.

Comment: @Karen -- I see. You've done the hard part already then ;)   Simply use `write()` -- it's just like `read()` but the opposite direction.

Comment: And what file descriptor i must use? 
**write (1, buffer, sizeof(buffer)** something like this ?

Comment: Use the exact same descriptor you used to read from; `fd` as returned from `open()` in your example.